# INSERT COM JOIN DUPLICANDO DADOS

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, join

Olá, tenho essas 3 tabelas no meu banco de dados:

```
Table colaboradores
Table cursos
Table c_vendas_itens
```

Gostaria de fazer um join das três tabelas e salvar em uma outra, consigo fazer isso através da query abaixo, porém cada vez que tenho um dado novo na tabela c_vendas_itens tenho que realizar o join novamente e então os dados ficam duplicados, alguém sabe como posso resolver essa situação?
Estou executando essa query numa trigger de inserção na tabela c_vendas_itens.

```
    INSERT INTO c_tabela_auxiliar 
(
cod_venda_item,
status_venda,
cpf_colab,
cod_venda,
cod_curso,
nome_curso,
categoria_venda,
nome_colab,
banco,
dv,
agencia,
conta,
valor_venda_item,
valor_repasse_item
)
select 
ven.cod_venda_item,
ven.status_venda,
cur.cpf_colab,
ven.codVenda,
cur.codCurso,
cur.nome,
cur.categoria,
col.nome,
col.banco,
col.dv,
col.agencia,
col.conta,
ven.valorVendaItem,
ven.valorRepasse

from c_vendas_itens as ven 
inner join cursos as cur on (cur.codCurso = ven.cod_curso)               
inner join colaboradores as col on (col.cpf = cur.cpf_colab);
```

Comment: Os dados vão estar duplicados de qualquer jeito, estarão nas 3 tabelas e nessa auxiliar, pra que essa outra tabela? É algum tipo de backup?

Comment: O campo `cod_venda_item` se repete na tabela `c_venda_itens` ou ele é uma primary key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo nome que está no campo `cod_venda_item`, imagino que seja uma primary key com o identificador de cada item daquela venda específica.

Adicione na sua consulta um `LEFT JOIN` com a mesma tabela que está sendo feito o `INSERT` e veja se o item não existe nela para ser adicionado:

```
 INSERT INTO c_tabela_auxiliar 
 (
     cod_venda_item,
     status_venda,
     cpf_colab,
     cod_venda,
     cod_curso,
     nome_curso,
     categoria_venda,
     nome_colab,
     banco,
     dv,
     agencia,
     conta,
     valor_venda_item,
     valor_repasse_item
 )
 SELECT ven.cod_venda_item,
        ven.status_venda,
        cur.cpf_colab,
        ven.codVenda,
        cur.codCurso,
        cur.nome,
        cur.categoria,
        col.nome,
        col.banco,
        col.dv,
        col.agencia,
        col.conta,
        ven.valorVendaItem,
        ven.valorRepasse
 FROM c_vendas_itens as ven 
INNER JOIN cursos cur 
   ON (cur.codCurso = ven.cod_curso)               
INNER JOIN colaboradores col 
   ON (col.cpf = cur.cpf_colab)
 LEFT JOIN c_tabela_auxiliar aux
   ON aux.cod_curso = ven.cod_curso
  AND aux.cpf_colab = col.cpf
  AND aux.cod_venda_item = ven.cod_venda_item
WHERE aux.cod_venda_item IS NULL;
```

Comment: muito obrigado, sua resposta foi a solução para o problema... :D

Comment: Por nada meu caro! Se minha resposta te ajudou a resolver o problema e pode ajudar outras pessoas, marque-a como resposta aceita e dê um voto positivo por favor. Assim as pessoas entendem que a resposta foi a solução.

Comment: certo, o voto não posso dar ainda pois sou novo no site e ainda não tenha 15 de reputação, assim que tiver o faço, mais uma vez muito obrigado.. :)

Comment: Eu entendo, a resposta aceita já ajuda demais, muito obrigado!!!